# Angular 4 using Web Speech API

Tags: angular, typescript, speech

I try to use the Web Speech API Interfaces (https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/) with a angular (version 4.25) and a asp core web-server. All is build by the visual studio 2017 (version 15.7.1). I add the 
@types/webspeechapi typedefinions to the package.json (version 0.0.29)

My (angular) componente looks like:

```
 /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/webspeechapi/index.d.ts" />
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'home',
        templateUrl: './home.component.html'
    })
    export class HomeComponent {

        constructor() {

            var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
...
```

Compiler has no erros at design time. But if i try to open the page i got a 500 error-message **NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined**

The console log of the web-server in vs is the same.

I want to use the typing definitions but why and who tries to resolve the
type SpeechRecognition?

Comment: Well, you didn't import `SpeechRecognition` nor `SpeechGrammarList`. Note that the `/// <reference` is ONLY for Visual Studio, it is treated as any comment by TypeScript/JavaScript

Comment: They must have in there are no compiler errors?

Comment: What browser you testing in? The API doesn't work on all browsers as yet... Check the browser support compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan was right with his hint, Chrome support this feature but only with webkit-prefixe.

So i insert a checking

```
var reg: SpeechRecognition;
var typ = typeof SpeechRecognition;

reg = typ === "undefined" ? new webkitSpeechRecognition() :
                                new SpeechRecognition();
```

This works for FF and Chrome.